# Regex For Report Section Headings and Subheadings

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

Edited with corner cases.

I need to write a regular expression that can match section heading and subheading from a PDF file the one below. Headers are a number followed by a period and then a title that can be one or more words in all CAPS.

(1. SCOPE) or (2. APPLICABLE DOCUMENTS) would be considered a heading.

The paragraph body below the heading contain Subheadings with ascending numbers following the number of the header and a title typically ending with a period.

(1.1 Scope.), (1.1.1 Classification.), (1.2 Definitions), and (1.3 Abbreviations, Acronyms, and Symbols.) are subheadings.

```
100
07482
1. SCOPE
1.1 Scope. This specification establishes general requirements ...
1.1.1 Classification. This specification contains the following ...
1.2 Definitions....
Acceptance Test Procedure – The procedure which defines those tests 
1.3 Abbreviations, Acronyms, and Symbols.
```

I need a regular expression that matches the heading and if possible the subheadings.

[image]

When I run the code above it can match the headings and subheading but it will also match any text that starts with a number and ends with a space or words behind the space.

I'm using now shown below can match the first number scheme and the first word. It works for section 1.1, 1.1.1, and 1.2 but if I have a section with a title that has multiple words like section 1.3 it does not work.

^(\d+(?:.\d+)*)\s([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)

any suggestions would be apprecitated.

I Tried.

^(\d+(?:.\d+)*)\s([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)

and I expected it to match 1.3 Abbreviations, Acronyms, and Symbols. but it only matched 1.3 abbreviations.

Comment: Hi Cary, sorry I am a little new at this I edited my post to add more clarity. Please let me know if this cleared things up or if you can give me more tips to help with my questions I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JmMH2A/1)):

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?\s*[^.\n\r]+\.?
```

- `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` - Match number with any dot + number afterwards
- `\.?` - optionally match a dot
- `[^.\n\r]+\.?` - match everything until a dot or new line

---

```py
import re

text = '''\
1. SCOPE
1.1 Scope. This specification establishes general requirements for Supplier-designed components. A comprehensive definition of the item to be developed will be contained in the Component Detail Design Specification invoking this general specification.
1.1.1 Classification. This specification contains the following class(es). Unless otherwise specified, the requirements herein apply to all Classes.
CLASS A
1.2 Definitions. For the purpose of this specification, the following definitions shall apply:
Acceptance Test Procedure – The procedure which defines those tests performed on the component after manufacture to demonstrate conformance to the specified acceptance requirements and to verify manufacture quality.
Ambient Bay – Atmosphere inside the propulsion system bay.
Blade Out – Used to describe the event when a fan, compressor, or turbine blade liberates from the rotor.
1.3 Abbreviations, Acronyms, and Symbols.'''

for title in re.findall(r'^\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?\s*[^.\n\r]+\.?', text, flags=re.M):
    print(title)
```

Prints:

```
1. SCOPE
1.1 Scope.
1.1.1 Classification.
1.2 Definitions.
1.3 Abbreviations, Acronyms, and Symbols.
```

---

EDIT: With updated input ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6s9xJc/1)):

```py
import re

text = '''\
100
07482
1. SCOPE
1.1 Scope. This specification establishes general requirements ...
1.1.1 Classification. This specification contains the following ...
1.2 Definitions....
Acceptance Test Procedure – The procedure which defines those tests
1.3 Abbreviations, Acronyms, and Symbols.
'''

for title in re.findall(r'^\d+\.[\d.]* [^.\n\r]+\.?', text, flags=re.M):
    print(title)
```

Prints:

```
1. SCOPE
1.1 Scope.
1.1.1 Classification.
1.2 Definitions.
1.3 Abbreviations, Acronyms, and Symbols.
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It is definitely working better but it is picking up any section of text that starts with a number. for example. a section of text like 20 milliamperes. gets picked up and not just section headers. Is there a way to make the start of the regex more specific to exclude these instances?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows given a text output from `pdftotext`

where txt is

```
100
07482
1. SCOPE
1.1 Scope. This specification establishes general requirements ...
1.1.1 Classification. This specification contains the following ...
1.2 Definitions....
Acceptance Test Procedure – The procedure which defines those tests 
1.3 Abbreviations, Acronyms, and Symbols.
20 milliamperes
```

etc.

`type pdfout.txt |findstr /R "^[0-9]\." >headings.txt`

gives a clean result

```
1. SCOPE
1.1 Scope. This specification establishes general requirements ...
1.1.1 Classification. This specification contains the following ...
1.2 Definitions....
1.3 Abbreviations, Acronyms, and Symbols.
```

It is blunt but workable. For a bigger range use
`type pdfout.txt |findstr /R "^[0-9]*\."`

```
1. SCOPE
1.1 Scope. This specification establishes general requirements ...
1.1.1 Classification. This specification contains the following ...
1.2 Definitions....
1.3 Abbreviations, Acronyms, and Symbols.
10. Ten
10.1 more..
100. Hundreds too
```

So to drag and drop a PDF on such a shortcut command it can be

`pdftotext -raw "%~1" pdfout.txt&&type pdfout.txt |findstr /R "^[0-9]*\.">headings.txt`

Crude but effective for most cases, since we just want the raw entries.